# Change default R versions in windows

Tags: r, version, default, compatibility

Some packages need updated version of R (3.2). But sometimes you need a R dependent software which needs former versions (flexarray: R version 2.15). I have both versions installed but the latest installed version is recognized as default. Then I should reinstall R.2.15 for flexarray. Do you have any recommendation to stop reinatallations? Thanks

Comment: Does FlexArray give the choice of the R: version?

Comment: No need to reinstall.  Just modify your path.  Alternatively, permanently set  your path to R-2.15 but set R-3.1 as the default in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks. Flexarray doesn't ask for R version. When the default is not R-2.15 it prompts. I could change the path in R studio to R-3.1. Is there a way to change the default for flexarray in windows?

Comment: What happens if you build `flexarray` from source under 3.1.2?  And if that doesn't work, consider rewriting the function you want your self -- it might be a fun challenge.

Comment: @Carl; 'flexarray' is dependent of 'AUTOSTAT' software which is R dependent. Yes, it would be a fun challenge. thanks